# Add item to binded combobox to list

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, bindingsource

I have a combobox binded to a list like this

```
public List<CustomerLanguage> CurrentCustomerLanguageList
    {
        get { return _currentCustomerLanguageList; }
        set
        {
            _currentCustomerLanguageList = value;

            bsCustomerLanguages.DataSource = Presenter.CustomerLanguageToProxy(value);
            cbLanguage.DataSource = bsCustomerLanguages.DataSource;
            cbLanguage.DisplayMember = "LanguageName";
            cbLanguage.ValueMember = "Id";
        }
    }
```

On the form i have + - buttons which must allow to add or delete items inside combobox.

The problem is: i dont know how to add new item to binding source and the list without full refresh of combobox.
Of course when i add, selected value must remains and no selectedvaluechanged event must be raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'bsCustomerLanguages' is a `BindingSource` ? In that case it should work if you set `cbLanguage.DataSource = bsCustomerLanguages` and add to bsCustomerLanguages directly

Comment: But this will refresh all items in combobox ? and i lose selected value ?

Comment: Not if you set the combobox's datasource to the bindingsource (bsCustomerLanguages) instead of bsCustomerLanguages.DataSource. The bindingsource has its own currencymanager, which means as much that it remembers its current position. If the datasource of the combobox is set to the bindingsource, it will sync the position of the bindingsource with its selecteditem